# imap fecthing in php

Tags: php, imap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP imap problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158961/php-imap-problems)

why are some of the characters messed up when displayed;

here is my code

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());


$emails = imap_search($inbox,'TEXT "$variable"');


if($emails) {


  $output = '';


  rsort($emails);


  foreach($emails as $email_number) {


    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);




    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
  }

  echo $output;
}
```

the output for the email was getting =3 and other weird characters
file is edited, see the answer given,

Comment: Please search the site, this question was *just* asked yesterday.  This is quoted-printable encoding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158961/php-imap-problems

Comment: oh sorry guys >< please close the question and i upvote for your link

Answer (score 0):

the answer to this is to use this function

imap_qprint